# input type text not going in the same position?

Tags: css

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7LUV4/

As you can see,

```
.text {
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  outline: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0);
box-shadow:         7px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.1s ease;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  border: 1px solid #CFCACC;
  border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
-moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
-webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
margin: 5px 20px;
word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

That is the code i'm using, It uses :focus for it's transition but the thing is, it's not staying at the same position. it's just floating from right to left, How do I fix this?

If possible, please?

Comment: What do you mean by 'floating from right to left' ? Do you mean you are trying to get the input boxes to align vertically?

Comment: FYI, the center tag is deprecated (I'm honestly surprised it still works).  If you want to increase the spacing between elements, use margins instead of multiple `<br />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the proper styles to `label`:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Here you make label display as a inline block element, give it exact width, and make text align to right. Hence, you get the inputs nicely aligned under each other.

Btw, it's not good to style *all* labels like this. You'd better give some id to the form and use `#myForm label` as the selector.

See in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/7LUV4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```css
input.text, label.alt{
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 150px;
}

label.alt{
    text-align: left;
}
```

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7LUV4/4/)

Comment: @MightyPork I appreciate your comment. Could you please explain 'useless junk' and 'worse result' ?

Comment: Well, I don't see why you'd use the asterisk hack, IE7 is really old, but whatever. Use it if you like. Zoom is non-standard property and is really useless here. `vertical-align` is not needed, as it's the default value in most cases: as you can see in the fiddle, it works fine even without it. In the end, your style is narrowed down to display and width. And the worse result mentioned is that you have shrunk the input field unnecessarily, and the labels should be aligned to right if you don't want the form to look real bad.

Comment: I agree that IE7 is really old but does that mean we can ignore it? Does the OP say that he is targeting specific browser version? ISN'T IT ALWAYS BETTER TO HAVE CODE THAT DOESN'T BREAK? About vertical-align, again you yourself say 'most cases'. How do you know what size in necessary and unnecessary for the OP? And I think the guy is smart enough to increase/decrease the size according to his needs. About the last statement - now that's upto individual perspective and taste isn't it?

Comment: oh right, keep it if you like it this way. But you can at least format your code :P